# How to rebuild kernel in Galaxy S7(SM-G930S)

Tags: kernel, galaxy

I do not know how to build kernel in Galaxy S7(SM-G930S).

Could you please tell me about it.

Below is the process of building the kernel.

1. Download Galaxy S7 kernel source in Samsung open source site.
2. Change the kernel source and make it compile
3. Extract pure boot.img in Galaxy S7.
4. Unpack boot.img using mkboot
5. copy kernel image from compiled kernel to pure kernel.
6. Repack boot.img using mkboot
7. Translate it to tar file
8. Push tar file in Galaxy S7 using Odin.
9. reboot.

I try this process. but i failed with "Kernel is not seandroid enforcing"

I really want to know about rebuilding kernel.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The same error "**[Kernel is not Seandroid Enforcing](https://geekermag.com/kernel-not-seandroid-enforcing/)**"  message is very common with Samsung devices. But users with Android phones from other manufacturers like Nokia, LG, HTC, Motorola and other have also been reporting about the same issue. I have faced this same issue, I follow some below steps like, download Odin – Samsung ROM Flashing Tool or TWRP – Custom Recovery images.

1) Extract the Odin zip file and from the extracted folder Run Odin 3 flashing tool.

2) In the tool, click on the AP button and select the TWRP Recovery image file which you have downloaded already for your device. The name should be like “twrp-3.2.1-0-c9lte.img.tar” or related.

3) Turn off the device.
For device with removable battery
Remove the battery wait for 2-3 seconds and reinsert it.
For device with non-removable battery
Hold the volume down button and power button for 2-3 seconds, and your phone will shut down.

4) Now Press and hold the Volume Down + Home + Power button at the same time until you see download mode screen. After that Press, the volume up button and connect the phone to PC using the official data cable and leave your device.
When the phone is connected to the computer, in the tool ID:COM will turn blue showing a code 0:{COM7}. It can 0:{COM8} 0:{COM3} or related.

5) On the computer press the Start button available at the bottom. Now let the tool flash the recovery on your phone. Once flashing process is completed, you will see Green color box written “Pass” message inside it.
Your phone will automatically reboot normally without showing an error message, i.e., Kernal is Not Seandroid Enforcing.